# How to prevent XSS host-header vulnerabilitie ?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, xss

An OSWAP scan reveal a XSS vulnerabilitie on my website.

The problem : When specify a wrong host, i got the value in the response.
[Postman response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnPcg.png)
While the return is 500, can it be exploit ?

I see lot of things about this in the web but not realy how to fix it.
I'm not sure if the problem come from my PHP configuration or Apache.

I found that : [How to exploit HTTP "Host" header XSS vulnerability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536668/how-to-exploit-http-host-header-xss-vulnerability) 
Would it be a solution in this case ?

httpd version : 2.4.33 / PHP 5.6 and Zend Framework 2.4

Comment: it can be exploited as soon as you use it raw. I've ever seen it on hacking challenge

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com might be better suited for this question.